# 16 bit mouse click limit on picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, click, mouse, picturebox

This is a C# question.
I have a form.  On the form I have a panel.  On the panel I have a picture box with a very large scrollable bitmap (Y >> 32768).  The picture box click event does not fire when the picture box Y is greater than 32767.  I understand that mouse clicks are limited to 16 bits.

Is there way to get a mouse click of the underlying panel so I can compute Y from the scroll bar positon and the y coordinate of the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another approach, such as "downscale" the bitmap to 32k size (or less) before to display it rather to display it in full size ? You could get the real X / Y position by multiply its value by the downscaling factor.

It don't know if there is an easy way to cross the 32k barrier but even if you could, I guess that the UI will be very slow according the size of your picture...