# Change point X and Y variables to int32 C#

Tags: c#, point

I have a question. Is it possible to change X and Y point values type from int to Int32? I have panel 50 000 pixels wide and I can only recognize the X dimension up to about 32k.

```
public void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       Point point = pictureBox2.PointToClient(MousePosition);
       MessageBox.Show(point.ToString());
       MessageBox.Show(point.X.ToString()); 
    }
```

This is my code, I need change X to Int32. Any solution? Thanks in advance,

Comment: `int` and `Int32` are the same.

Comment: If it's stopping at 32k, then you probably have a 16 bit int (short) somewhere. 16 bit signed ints only go up to 32,767, which would make sense. Without a MCVE though, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 5):

An [`int` is `Int32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care), it is just an alias for it. The [max value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32), which you are well within.

(An int is a 32 bit number, it does not mean it can only go to 32,000.)

Comment: So why when I click on my image I can get value only from first 32k rows and the rest of 50k is 'non-clickable'?

Comment: You need to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help. It is not related to the size of an int however.

Comment: I think that the problem is that there is 16 bit mouse click limit on picturebox. Am I right?

Comment: You are probably right, the max value of an `Int16` (or `short`) is 32767. Edit: You are, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/22951737/1218281

Comment: It looks like shorts are used in the actual windows API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx